# Can you configure all minsize for row/column all at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter app I am working on for a note recall tool. My problem is in the .grid layout. I am wondering if there is a way to configure the minsize of all rows and all columns using `.columnconfigure()` and `.rowconfigure()` using something like a range to define all rows/columns. Right now I have to define `minsize=` for ever row and ever column separately. It just seams like there should be an easier way to define all the rows/columns at once.

here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter.font
import subprocess as sub
import tkinter.messagebox


#~~~~~~~~~~~< spacer grid >~~~~~~~~~~~
spacerC0=Label(root, text="0").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
spacerC1=Label(root, text="1").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
spacerC2=Label(root, text="2").grid(row = 1, column = 2)
spacerC3=Label(root, text="3").grid(row = 1, column = 3)
spacerC4=Label(root, text="4").grid(row = 1, column = 4)
spacerC5=Label(root, text="5").grid(row = 1, column = 5)
spacerC6=Label(root, text="6").grid(row = 1, column = 6)
spacerC7=Label(root, text="7").grid(row = 1, column = 7)
spacerC8=Label(root, text="8").grid(row = 1, column = 8)
spacerC9=Label(root, text="9").grid(row = 1, column = 9)
root.columncel(root, text="0").grid(row = 1)
spacerR1=Label(root, text="1").grid(row = 2)
spacerR2=Label(root, text="2").grid(row = 3)
spacerR3=Label(root, text="3").grid(row = 4)
spacerR4=Label(root, text="4").grid(row = 5)
spacerR5=Label(root, text="5").grid(row = 6)
spacerR6=Label(root, text="6").grid(row = 7)
spacerR7=Label(root, text="7").grid(row = 8)
spacerR8=Label(root, text="8").grid(row = 9)
spacerR9=Label(root, text="9").grid(row = 10)
root.rowconfigure(0, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(1, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(2, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(3, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(4, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(5, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(6, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(7, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(8, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(9, minsize=60)
root.rowconfigure(10, minsize=60)
```

Comment: nothing specifically built in, but a simple loop is all you need.

Comment: Just got a notices for "popular question" on this post and I came to take a look... This is so painful to look at now that I have leaned how to write DRY code. :D This was one of my 1st post and now I wouldn't even dream of writing code like this lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

```
for row_num in range(root.grid_size()[1]):
    root.rowconfigure(row_num, minsize=60)
```

Edit: you could combine that with a loop to create all those Labels:

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~< spacer grid >~~~~~~~~~~~
for col_num in range(1, 10):
    spacer=Label(root, text=str(col_num))
    spacer.grid(row = 0, column = col_num)
for row_num in range(10):
    spacer=Label(root, text=str(row_num))
    spacer.grid(row = row_num, column = 0)
    root.rowconfigure(row_num, minsize=60)
```

Comment: I see. So what is the [1] part?. I see how this should work but can you help me understand the syntax of it? I can see that it calls a range and for each row its applying minsize=60 to it. But I would like to understand the root.grid_size()[1] part.

Comment: Grid_size() returns a 2-tuple containing the number of columns and rows. By using the [] you select the rows or the columns. For more info check: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: `grid_size()` returns a tuple of the number of columns, number of rows. The `[1]` pulls out the number of rows only.

Comment: so would [0] pull out number of columns?

Comment: Yep. Or if you wanted to be more clear: `num_cols, num_rows = root.grid_size()` and then use `num_rows` in the loop. I edited my answer with another way, too.

Comment: @Jonathan The loop you provided worked perfectly. Thank you all for the advice this is exactly what I was looking to do and it provides me with a way to manipulate the rows and columns without having to change several lines of code each time I want to change my formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a quite small (62 lines) DSL to layout TKinter grids similar to Flutter.

Example:

```
from tkinter import W, Tk
from tkinter import ttk
from grid import Grid, Row, RowConfigure, ColumnConfigure, GridOptions, Dummy

window = Tk()
window.title("Grid Layout DSL")
window.geometry('400x400')

def on_click():
    print("Hello from Grid layout")

layout = Grid(
    parent = window,
    row_configure = RowConfigure(pad = 10),
    col_configure = ColumnConfigure(pad = 10),
    grid_options = GridOptions(sticky=W),
    rows = [
        Row(
            children=[
                ttk.Label(window ,text = "First Name:"), 
                ttk.Entry(window)]),
        Row(
            children=[
                ttk.Label(window ,text = "Last Name:"), 
                ttk.Entry(window)]),
        Row(
            children=[
                ttk.Label(window ,text = "Email:"), 
                ttk.Entry(window)]),
        Row(
            children=[
                ttk.Label(window ,text = "Number:"), 
                ttk.Entry(window)]),
        Row(
            children=[
                Dummy(window), 
                ttk.Button(window ,text="Submit", command=on_click)]),
    ]
)

layout.layout()
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

The code is just a grid.py (62 lines) file available for free here:
https://gist.github.com/mnesarco/df03075d8806ed72d784ccabc2d52f12

Answer (score 0):

I just came back from a reallllyyyy long trip.
Sorry for the delay.
The OP only asks for the rowconf part. So thats:

`root.rowconfigure(list(range(11)), minsize=60)`

AS @Novel pointed out in his answer, we can make this more dynamic by abstracting away the hardcoded magic'11' :

`root.rowconfigure(list(range(root.grid_size()[1])), minsize=60)`